# window.location not working with window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code,

```
$('.editLayout #changeLayout').click(function() {
   $('html').height($(document).height());
   $('#fluidWrap').hide('scale');
   $.ajax({
       data: {
           mainLayout: true
       },
       success: function() {
          alert(window.location.href);
          window.location = window.location.href;
       }
   });
return false;
});
```

When the `alert` returns I get a valid url with a hash an example being,

`http://www.example.com/edit#_layout`

But the page does not refresh, if I hit f5 though the page refreshes as normal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

**UPDATED** 
(And here hacky solution for chrome)

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},100)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, what could be causing this, before it was working but there was no hash tag.

Comment: Which browser you trying ? Chrome ?

Comment: Ye chrome, I test in chrome first then others

Comment: Thanks worked brilliantly didn't expect chrome to have any bugs flying about it is normally up to date with everything!

Answer (score 1):

Updating a hash wont reload the page, and by the same token setting the page href to a href that contains a hash wont refresh it either. Try this:

```
alert(window.location.href);
window.location = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```